# Is Outlook web addin required to register with Azure AD in order to submit to Seller Dashboard?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, office-store

We are trying to submit our Outlook Web Add-in to the Seller Dashboard.

According to [the instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/use-the-seller-dashboard-to-submit-to-the-office-store):

> "If you're submitting Office 365 web apps to the Seller Dashboard, make sure that you have registered your web app with Azure Active Directory."

However, we are not using Azure AD to do OAuth. Furthermore, we are not sure if this restriction of Office 365 apps applies to Outlook add-in as Office add-ins and Outlook add-ins are listed as two separate entries on the [submission checklist](http://Is%20Outlook%20web%20addin%20required%20to%20register%20with%20Azure%20AD%20in%20order%20to%20submit%20to%20Seller%20Dashboard?).

Want to know if we really need to do this for our add-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure AD registration is only needed if you intend to use the getAccessTokenAsync API. Otherwise you can skip it for Outlook Add-ins.